# Masking a substring if it matches the list element, Python

Tags: python, masking

I have a task:
I need to mask a part of the string if it matches with the element of the list.

```
stringValue = "My name is Jackie Brown! I am from Louisiana."
surnameList = ["Brown", "Louisiana", ...]
```

In this example, the desired output would be:

```
maskedString = "My name is Jackie *****! I am from *****."
```

The length of masked substring (in this case, 5 *'s) is not important, as long as the string is masked.

Here's my initial function:

```
import re
def maskSurname(stringValue, surnameList):
    indexList = []
    splitList = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]',' ',stringValue).split()
    for x in splitList:
        for z in surnameList:
            if x == z:
                index = splitList.index(x)
                indexList.append(index)
    for y in indexList:
        splitList[y] = "*****"
    return listToString(splitList)
```

That seems to get the job done, however, it removes all of the punctuation marks, which is not ideal, but not a major issue.
The output of the function `maskSurname()` is a joined list:

```
My name is Jackie ***** I am from *****
```

How would I go about making this more efficiently? At the moment, the list of words to be masked contains ~500 words. The words really have no pattern, it seems that I can't use regex in a way that I know of.
These functions will be used with JSON data.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not ideal, but you can try something like this: `re.sub('|'.join(surnameList), '*****', stringValue)`

Answer (score 0):

Why use regex and add overhead when you can just do `str.replace`:

```
>>> stringValue = "My name is Jackie Brown! I am from Louisiana."
>>> surnameList = ["Brown", "Louisiana"]
>>> for i in surnameList:
...     stringValue = stringValue.replace(i, "*****")
... 
>>> stringValue
'My name is Jackie *****! I am from *****.'
```

Comment: This is a great solution, thanks! However, it does introduce vulnerability to case sensitivity. I can't add .lower() to an i in for loop.